# How to add few parameters to URL with form in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel

I have problem with forms in laravel.

**web.php (routes)**

```
Route::get('/test/{param1}/{param2}', [
    'as' => 'test', 'uses' => 'TestController@test'
]);
```

**TestController.php**

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function test($param1, $param2)
    {
        $key = Test::take(100)
            ->where('offer_min', '<=', $param1)
            ->where('offer_max', '>=', $param1)
            ->where('period_min', '<=', $param2)
            ->where('period_max', '>=', $param2)
            ->get();
        return view('test.index')->with('key', $key);
    }
}
```

And I want to add the form which will generate URL from inputs.

Something like that:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => array('calculator', $_GET['param1'], $_GET['param2']), 'method' => 'get')) !!}
    <input type="number" name="param1" value="Something">
    <input type="number" name="param2" value="Something else">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This should generate URL like this:

```
http://your.site/test/123/1234
```

... but does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `POST` method to send form data:

```
Route::post('/test', ['as' => 'test', 'uses' => 'TestController@test']);
```

Then use correct route name and remove parameters:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'test']) !!}
```

Then get data in the controller using `Request` object:

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    $key = Test::take(100)
        ->where('offer_min', '<=', $request->param1)
        ->where('offer_max', '>=', $request->param1)
        ->where('period_min', '<=', $request->param2)
        ->where('period_max', '>=', $request->param2)
        ->get();

    return view('test.index')->with('key', $key);
}
```

When you use [resource routes and controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers), you should use `POST` or `PUT` methods to send the form data.